# How to use users phone lock in flutter application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-ios, flutter-android

does anyone knows how I can use users default phone lock code (fingerprint, passcode, pattern, etc) to control access to certain screens within my Flutter App?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth

Check this package

I used this package for fingerprint

Comment: thanks, I will give it a look.

Comment: Thanks, @masumbillahsanjid, I can implement my use case with this package.